# How do I parse and convert DateTime to the RFC 3339 with C++

Tags: c++, datetime, rfc3339

How do I parse a string equivalent [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) to any type of regular DateTime structure? The [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) date-time format is used in a number of specifications such as the [Atom Syndication Format](http://atomenabled.org/).

Here is example of date time in ATOM([RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt)) format:

```
2005-08-15T15:52:01+04:00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete, but unfortunately unsatisfactory, and yet portable program  among the very latest versions of libc++, libstdc++, VS implementations, which parses the string in the format you show into a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

I could not find a `DateTime` to which you refer.  However `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` **is a** "DateTime" structure.  `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` is a count of some time duration (seconds, microseconds, nanoseconds, whatever) since some unspecified epoch.  And you can query `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` to find out what its time duration is.  And as it turns out, every implementation measures time since New Years 1970 neglecting leap seconds.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>

template <class Int>
// constexpr
Int
days_from_civil(Int y, unsigned m, unsigned d) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::digits >= 18,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit unsigned integer");
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<Int>::digits >= 20,
             "This algorithm has not been ported to a 16 bit signed integer");
    y -= m <= 2;
    const Int era = (y >= 0 ? y : y-399) / 400;
    const unsigned yoe = static_cast<unsigned>(y - era * 400);      // [0, 399]
    const unsigned doy = (153*(m + (m > 2 ? -3 : 9)) + 2)/5 + d-1;  // [0, 365]
    const unsigned doe = yoe * 365 + yoe/4 - yoe/100 + doy;         // [0, 146096]
    return era * 146097 + static_cast<Int>(doe) - 719468;
}

using days = std::chrono::duration
    <int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>>;

namespace std
{

namespace chrono
{

template<class charT, class traits>
std::basic_istream<charT,traits>&
operator >>(std::basic_istream<charT,traits>& is, system_clock::time_point& item)
{
    typename std::basic_istream<charT,traits>::sentry ok(is);
    if (ok)
    {
        std::ios_base::iostate err = std::ios_base::goodbit;
        try
        {
            const std::time_get<charT>& tg = std::use_facet<std::time_get<charT> >
                                                           (is.getloc());
            std::tm t = {};
            const charT pattern[] = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S";
            tg.get(is, 0, is, err, &t, begin(pattern), end(pattern)-1);
            if (err == std::ios_base::goodbit)
            {
                charT sign = {};
                is.get(sign);
                err = is.rdstate();
                if (err == std::ios_base::goodbit)
                {
                    if (sign == charT('+') || sign == charT('-'))
                    {
                        std::tm t2 = {};
                        const charT pattern2[] = "%H:%M";
                        tg.get(is, 0, is, err, &t2, begin(pattern2), end(pattern2)-1);
                        if (!(err & std::ios_base::failbit))
                        {
                            auto offset = (sign == charT('+') ? 1 : -1) *
                                          (hours{t2.tm_hour} + minutes{t2.tm_min});
                            item = system_clock::time_point{
                                days{days_from_civil(t.tm_year+1900, t.tm_mon+1,
                                                     t.tm_mday)} +
                                hours{t.tm_hour} + minutes{t.tm_min} + seconds{t.tm_sec} -
                                offset};
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            err |= ios_base::failbit;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        err |= ios_base::failbit;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    err |= ios_base::failbit;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                err |= ios_base::failbit;
            }
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            err |= std::ios_base::badbit | std::ios_base::failbit;
        }
        is.setstate(err);
    }
    return is;
}

}  // namespace chrono
}  // namespace std

int
main()
{
    std::istringstream infile("2005-08-15T15:52:01+04:00");
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp;
    infile >> tp;
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
}
```

This has been tested against libc++, libstdc++-5.0 and VS-2015 and produces respectively:

```
1124106721000000
1124106721000000000
11241067210000000
```

On libc++ this is a count of microseconds since New Years 1970, neglecting leap seconds.  On libstdc++-5.0 it is a count of nanoseconds, and on VS-2015 it is a count of 100 nanoseconds.

The problem with this solution is that it involves inserting a function into the std namespace.  In the future the C++ committee may decide to insert this same function into the same namespace which could invalidate your code.

Another problem with this code is that it is horribly complicated.  It is a shame that the standard does not provide a simpler solution.

Another problem with this code is that it does not use the simpler "%F", "%T", and "%z" parsing patterns documented in the C standard (though documented as formatting patterns).  I experimentally discovered their use was not portable.

Another problem with this code is that it will require gcc-5.0.  If you're running gcc-4.9, you're out of luck.  You'll have to parse things yourself.  I was not able to test VS implementations prior to VS-2015.  libc++ should be ok (though even libc++ does not support "%z").

You can convert the `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` back into a "broken down" structure if desired via the [formulas here](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html). However if that is your ultimate goal, it would be more efficient to modify the code above to parse directly into your "broken down" structure instead of into a `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point`.

Disclaimer:  Only very lightly tested.  I'm happy to update this answer with any bug reports.

**Update**

In the years since I first gave this answer I have written a library which does all the computations above with a far more concise syntax.

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::istringstream infile{"2005-08-15T15:52:01+04:00"};
    sys_seconds tp;  // This is a system_clock time_point with seconds precision
    infile >> parse("%FT%T%Ez", tp);
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch() << " is " << tp << '\n';
}
```

You can find `"date.h"` [here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  It is a free, open-source, header only library.  At the [this link](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) there are also links to [full documentation](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html), and for `"date.h"` even a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo).  Though the [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo) was created prior to the implementation of the `parse` function.

The output of the above program is:

```
1124106721s is 2005-08-15 11:52:01
```

which gives both the seconds since epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), and the date/time in UTC (taking the offset into account).

On the off chance that you need to count leap seconds since the epoch, [another library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html) at this same GitHub link is available, but is not header only and requires a small amount of [installation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).  But using it is a simple modification of the program above:

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    std::istringstream infile{"2005-08-15T15:52:01+04:00"};
    utc_seconds tp;  // This is a utc_clock time_point with seconds precision
    infile >> parse("%FT%T%Ez", tp);
    std::cout << tp.time_since_epoch() << " is " << tp << '\n';
}
```

And the output is now:

```
1124106743s is 2005-08-15 11:52:01
```

The difference in code is that `"tz.h"` is now included instead of `"date.h"`, and `utc_seconds` is parsed instead of `sys_seconds`.  `utc_seconds` is still a `std::chrono::time_point`, but now based on a leap-second-aware clock.  The program outputs the same date/time, but the number of seconds since the epoch is now 22s greater as this is the number of leap seconds inserted between 1970-01-01 and 2005-08-15.